# corners of angled rect in 3d

Tags: python-3.x, geometry, coordinates, trigonometry

Ive got 2 points in 3d space (with the same y coordinate). Ill call them `c` and `m`. I want to find the corner points (marked in the pic as p1-p4) of a square with the width `w`. The important thing is, that the square is not parallel to the x-axis. If it were, (for `p1` as an example) I could just do:

```
p1.x = m.x + w / 2
p1.y = m.y + w / 2
p1.z = m.z
```

How would I do the same with a angled square? These are all the given points:

```
m; c
```

and lenghts:

```
w; d
```

[image: pic1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's multiple ways to do it, but here's one way.

If the two points are guaranteed to have the same y value, you should be able to do it as follows.

Take 'm - c' and call that *u*. Normalize *u*. Then take the cross product of *u* and the y axis to get *v*, a vector parallel to the xz plane that's perpendicular to *u*. (This can be optimized, but that's unlikely to be important.) Then take the cross product of *u* and *v* to get a third vector, *w*. Note that you can use 'm - c' or 'c - m', or use different orders for the cross-product arguments, and it'll still work, but the resulting vectors may point in different directions (but only opposite directions). You can also normalize at different points in the process and get the same results at the end.

Once you have m, *v*, and *w*, you can use some basic vector math to compute the corners.

[Edit: I see you have a variable named 'w', so I should clarify that the 'w' in my example is a different 'w' than yours. As for your 'w' and 'd', those would factor in in the vector math I mentioned at the end.]

Comment: Could you maybe go through what to do with the points c = (100,100,100); m = (120,100,130)? I just cant figure it out.

Comment: Is this part of a homework assignment? I'll try to help either way - I just want to be careful about giving an answer outright if it's homework.

Comment: Hahahah, no it's not for homework. It's just a personal project. I'm trying to render shapes in 3d space (which I got working) with perspective. (github.com/DinosaurMoritz/3dConsoleRender) Now I want to turn, as up to now I could only move up, down forward backward,left and right. I'm getting a square at rDis (render diatance) away and then from every point on that plane I draw a line to c (camera) and if it gets intercepted that point on the plane is dark. With this I'm trying to get the plane, but angled. (I am a student, but from highschool and Germany)

Comment: I'm not sure if a complete explanation would on-topic in the comments, but if you're still having trouble, maybe you could post what step you're stuck on. The first step is the vector subtraction, which should be straightforward (but feel free to ask if you're not clear on that). Then normalization (if you decide to normalize first). Then the cross product as described above, etc. If you can specify where you're having trouble, someone can probably help.

Comment: 1. With the points I suggested in the first comment: u=(20,0,30) 2. Normalise: (0.55,0,0.83) Now I don't know how to continue.

Comment: I'm happy to help, but working through it in detail may be off topic here :( I think there's a chat feature, but I've never used it, and there may be a reputation threshold. In any case, there aren't that many steps left. The next step is to take the cross product of u and the y axis (0, 1, 0). If you're not sure how to do that, I'd suggest going through some vector math tutorials, posting a new question, and/or asking someone you know. If there's something in particular you're stuck on, post back here and maybe we can sort it out.